# Add addional method to promise chain

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I use the following code which works OK,Currenlty the pars.getEx is returning a string to run to the **processExe** method,Now I need somehow to pass also **port** from other function to **processExe**,how can I do that ?

```
  var portscanner = require('portscanner');
  var Promise = require('bluebird');
  var fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require("fs"));
```

.....

```
    return fs.readFileAsync(filePath, 'utf8')
        .then(pars.getEx.bind(null, 'user'))
        .then(processExe.bind(null, 'exec'))
        .then(function (result) {
            return result.stdout;
        }, function (error) {
            return error;
        });
```

The processExe looks like following

```
function processExe(method, cmd) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        var child = child_process[method](cmd, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
```

The port can be achieved with the following OS

https://github.com/baalexander/node-portscanner

```
portscanner.findAPortNotInUse(3000, 4000, 'localhost', function (error, 

port) {
```

**UPDATE**

to the processExe I should provide the port like following

the port should come from the findPort

```
       var options = {
            PORT: port,
        };
```

and here i also pass **options**

```
var child = child_process[method](cmd,options, function (error, stdout,
```

Comment: `processExe` doesn't seem to have a `port` parameter.

Comment: @Bergi - yep since I dont know how is the right way to add it to it...

Comment: And how would the `port` be used within `processExe`? You do know that, don't you (just to make sure I understand the question). The function should stand on its own, so if it needs an additional parameter just give it a parameter. How it would be called is a different thing

Comment: @Bergi - in one min i'll update my question with answer to your question,thanks!

Comment: @Bergi - done I'll hope now its more clear :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want/need a parameter, just add a parameter:

```
function processExe(method, cmd, port) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var child = child_process[method](cmd, {
            PORT: port,
        }, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
            …
        });
        …
    });
}
```

As always, the asynchronous function should return a promise, how many parameters it has (one, two, or now three) doesn't matter. You should not try to find some special way to pass the values that are needed because the function will be used under certain circumstances, that's a separate concern and should not influence the design of your function.

Now, how to pass additional parameters when the function is invoked within a promise chain? Well, you seem to know that already, function expressions and `.bind` are at your service. The problem is rather that the source of your argument values is not a single promise, but rather two asynchronous processes - the one that reads and parses a file and the one that finds a port. Since both are async, we expect them both to return promises; you should be able to promisify `portscanner` just like you did `fs`.

When you have two or more promises, you can combine them using [`Promise.all`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.all.html):

```
return Promise.all([
    fs.readFileAsync(filePath, 'utf8').then(pars.getEx.bind(null, 'user')), 
    portscanner.findAPortNotInUseAsync(3000, 4000, 'localhost')
]).then(function(args) {
    return processExe('exec', args[0], args[1]);
})
```

We can simplify this a bit though by using [`Promise.join`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.join.html):

```
return Promise.join(
  fs.readFileAsync(filePath, 'utf8').then(pars.getEx.bind(null, 'user')), 
  portscanner.findAPortNotInUseAsync(3000, 4000, 'localhost'),
  processExe.bind(null, 'exec')
)
```

Comment: Bergi Thanks awesome!!!! 1+ Last question:) , assume that the options should be provided from other function to processExe ,how would you integrate it to the processExe ? I've used the join solution which is very nice!!!

Comment: What do you mean by "from other function"? Just call the function with the port as an argument.

Comment: Sorry for delay in my response...Assume that I need to get the options from other module function inside my project,How you will pass it to the processExe as addional param ? Thanks a lot for your assitance!

Comment: You mean instead of using `portscanner.findAPort…`? Then just use your module function in place of it.

Comment: Hi again, No I mean in addition,I need the to get the port from findAPortNotInUseAsync and pass it to the processExe and In addition to pass to it the option from external function,I want to sperate  as far as I can different logic's

Comment: `Promise.join` does work for three promises and a function just as well. Or you could nest two `join`s, the inner one producing a promise for the options object from the `findAPort…` and the external function.

Comment: Can you please provide example,now sure where to put it exactly and pass the parameter accordingly,Thank you sir!

Comment: Done I was able to do it !! Thanks expert!